# Why use javascript:void(0) instead of # in href?

Tags: javascript

I can see a lot of `<a href="javascript:void(0);">` on html pages. From I've read it does nothing by returning `undefined`. How is this different with `<href="#">`

Comment: `#` jumps to the top of the page.

Comment: #links in Modern browsers like Firefox and chrome. This causes the page to look for the available link (and jump to top if unavailable) in the page and scroll to the region. But Void does not do any action

Comment: Another question related to this: How about not include href attribute in <a>? For example <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doSomething();"> vs <a  onclick="doSomething();"

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
<a href="#">link</a>
```

adds # to the browser url and jumps to the top of the page.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">link</a>
```

simply "ignores" the link click.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">link</a>
```

also ignores the href.

Don't forget that in some cases javascript might be disabled (very uncommon).

Comment: Adding to that: `void 0` is essentially `undefined` - that's why browser will do nothing.

Comment: probably something like `href="#_"` should also avoid the need for `onclick="return false;"`, which IMHO is obtrusive!

Answer (score 4):

`#` might jump to a different location in the page. Plus, it modifies the URL

Comment: modifies the url is fine but jump is not. and here if it's just "#" then the jump is to the top of the page

Comment: huh? I'm confused, there's a bit of discrepancy in your comment. You say that **jump is not fine** and then that the **jump is to the top of the page**. I don't get it

Comment: which is why we use javascript:void(0) that **does not make the jump**

Comment: Mate, you lost the plot...looks like you are on a different conversation

Answer (score 4):

`href="javascript:void(0);` is for the case that you want it to do nothing , but still look as a link. ( blue and underline).

it's just like :`javascript:return undefined;`

Why ?

Because someone might do : `undefined=function (){}`

The `#` - is an anchor which sends you to the top of the page.